# cordova navigator.camera is undefined

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugin-camera

I have installed cordova-plugin-camera. Although, it gives me the following error.

navigator.camera is not defined.
Here is the code snippet. Thanks in advance!

```
 <body>
    <script>
       document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            console.log(typeof navigator.camera);
        }
    window.onload=onDeviceReady;
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the `window.onload=onDeviceReady;`

You are calling `onDeviceReady` twice, once before device is ready and then when it's ready.

Comment: I am new at this.So if I ask a silly question, don't mind me pls.But when I remove it, I can not see the log of "navigator.camera".

Comment: Ah, you also have to link cordova.js like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`